# Angular 2 Filter array and append data

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, multidimensional-array

Quick one, I've 2 arrays/ objects. One contains all items the other contains selected ID's from the first array.

My question is, what is the best way to loop through both arrays find selected items from the second array and if they are true append data to first array. What I'm trying to do is append true to the first array if the ID's match.

For example something like this:

```
this.categories.filter(
                        category => {

                            this.user.category_ids.filter(
                                selected => {
                                    if(selected == category._id) {
                                        var data = {'selected': true};

                                        category.push(data);
                                    }
                                }
                            );


                            console.log(category);
                        }
                    );
```

At the moment I'm looping through categories object then through user.category_ids and if the ID's match I want to append selected: true to first array object, if this makes sense. I get error:

```
core.es5.js:1084 ERROR TypeError: category.push is not a function
```

Which I don't understand why. I've also tried splice.

Also to me this doesn't seem like best approach, because I've 12 items in first array. And if all 12 are selected, second array will have 12 items. So looping through 12 * 12 to me is little expensive, memory wise.

Comment: have you initialized category = [];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
this.categories.map(category => {
    category.selected = this.user.category_ids.indexOf(category._id) !== -1;
    return category;
});
```

Comment: This actually is exactly what I was looking for. Simple yet does exactly what is needed. No need to loop through 2 arrays. Thanks! I will not be returning category though. Because I need to run through every item.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (selected == category._id) {
  category['selected'] = true;

  /* you can build a interface for category
   * or declare category as any
   * then you can write it as the below
   */
  // category.selected = true;
}
```

`push` is to add a new item to an array.

Comment: Yes this worked beautifully. I think building an interface for category will be best since object access via string literals is disallowed I think in Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly clarify if `categories` is an array of objects? If yes then you cant use push to add a new object since each element in the `categories` is an object and object don't have push method. Add new property to object instead using

`category.selected=true` or

`category['selected']=true;`

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- this.user.category_ids is a 'array of objects' as you are using 'category._id'.
- if ids match you want to add a key 'selected' whose value is true , to that object whose id is matched .

Solution:
 - You are getting this error category.push is not a function because category is an object not an array ,push only works with array.

```js
   if(selected == category._id) {
                                 category['selected']=true;
                                    }
```